# omiagent does not exit on sles 12

Tags: powershell, remote, sles12

We use powershell scripts on some sles 12 vms for testing purposes. The scripts are automatically started from a windows server. Now I see that every call of a single script starts a new instance of omiagent. That is ok, but the agents never exit. So the memory usage increases until the vms start swapping.

Does anybody know that problem and can tell a solution?

BTW: Calling the scripts per ssh is not a solution, because we transfer complex hashtables between the machines.

Comment: Please update with code that can reproduce the event.

Comment: @Colyn1337 sorry, I am not sure what you do request. On the caller side we use `InvokeCommand` and I think the content of the called script does not matter. A simple `Write-Host` should do. If this is the missing information I will test it and update the question.

Comment: Today I found this issue https://github.com/Microsoft/omi/issues/580 . It explains the problem but does not help solving my problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a solution but a workaround:

A script kills all processes with name `omiagent` but the last two startet. This script is started by cron every minute.

This workaround needs the following preconditions:

- There are only a few remote calls per minute.
- There are no parallel (or overlapping) remote calls.